# UICollectionview cellForItem return nil

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Error: Return nil

```
for index in 0...totalHobbies - 1 {       
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 1) 
    print(indexPath) // Print [1, 0]
    let cell  = CollectionInterest.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CommanCollectionViewCell
    print(cell.btnInterestToggle.isSelected)
    if cell.btnInterestToggle.isSelected {

    }
}
```

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: seems collection has 0 rows.

Comment: You're force casting the result. If the result is nil, or is the wrong type, your app crashes, **as expected**. No surprise. If you don't want that, handle your optionals properly.

Comment: multiple row  in collection view

Comment: `cellForItem(at:)` returns `nil` if the cell is not visible, that's said in the documentation of that method. Is it the case? What about safe unwrap instead of forced one? Also you should update the model too if needed doing the same in `tableView:cellForItem:`

Comment: Do not do this. Cells are not your data model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to very careful while working with optionals.

If you forcefully unwrap optional value then you get crash at run time. So in that case you can use `if let` or `guard let`.

```
for index in 0...totalHobbies - 1  {

        let indexPath = IndexPath(item: index, section: 1)

        if let cell  = CollectionInterest.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CommanCollectionViewCell {

            print(cell.btnInterestToggle.isSelected)
            if cell.btnInterestToggle.isSelected{

            }
        } else {
            print("not able to cast collection view cell class to `CommanCollectionViewCell` ")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Error this: not able to cast collection view cell class to `CommanCollectionViewCell`

Comment: CommanCollectionViewCell is use of two collection view its possible