# Swift - Getting nil in my item, while I am trying to access item via cellForItem

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am getting nil in my `UICollectionViewItem` if I am trying to get my item via `cellForItem`. But data is showing in my `UICollectionView`.
I am displaying data in my `UICollectionView` via remote. after `reloadData` when I try to access data via item. it returning nil.

Here's code for fetching data from remote and reload Collection View.

```
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, err) in
        guard let data = data else { return }

        do {

            let songs = try JSONDecoder().decode(yt.self, from: data)
            for sng in songs.items {
                if(sng.id.videoId==nil){
                    self.video_arr.append("xVrNFaeMvP8")

                    self.images.append("https://i.ytimg.com/vi/sGIm0-dQd8M/default.jpg")
                }else{
                    self.video_arr.append(sng.id.videoId)
                    self.images.append(sng.snippet.thumbnails.medium.url)
                }
                self.channelTitle.append(sng.snippet.channelTitle)
                self.titlesArr.append(sng.snippet.title!)

            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
                self.isAddedToFavourites()
            }

            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()

        } catch let jsonErr {
            print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
        }

        }.resume()
```

and Here's my code where I am getting my item.

```
func isAddedToFavourites(){
    for i in 0..<collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) - 1{
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: i, section: 0)
        let item = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! PlayerCollectionViewCell
        //This is returning nil
       print(item.musicTitle.text!)
    }
```

is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Looks like this is not the write way to access the data model of a `UICollectionView`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50873511/10900045

Comment: you should access data from songs.items[i] instead of from collectionView cell

Comment: @AbuUlHassan I can't access data from cellForItem(at:)?

Comment: @AbuUlHassan I want to change in my item, how can I do this? i.e if I want to change my image of UIButton link with my item

item.addToFavouriteButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "final2heart"), for: .normal)
I want to update my item in this way? how can I do this?

Comment: How are you creating the collectionview ? Is it inside UICollectionViewController or a UICollectionView ?

Comment: UiCollectionView

Answer (score 0):

> **cellForItem(at:)** The cell object at the corresponding index path or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.

You should use the data model `titlesArr` to access the data instead.

Refer [UICollectionview cellForItem return nil](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50873511/10900045)

Comment: I want to change in my item, how can I do this? i.e if I want to change my image of UIButton link with my item

item.addToFavouriteButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "final2heart"), for: .normal)
I want to update my item in this way? how can I do this?

Comment: You need to do that in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` of the collection view.

Comment: but it is returning nil

Comment: In the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` delegate method, get `titlesArr[indexPath.row]`, if you want to access the title.

Comment: I can't access my item outside the delegate method?

Comment: I don't quite get it. Your data model must be accessible within the delegate method. Could please post the relevant code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189428/discussion-between-haani-dev-and-jsloop).